# Including data via several linking tables in Sequelize

Tags: sequelize.js

I have the following tables in MySQL database:

1. Bands { id, name, ... }
2. People { id, name, ... }

// A person can be in one or more bands
// A band has one or more members

3. BandMembers { id, personId, bandId, isGuest, ... }
4. Instruments { id, name, ... }

// A band member can play one or more instruments in the same specific band
// Several band members of the same band can play same instruments (e.g. two guitarists, all members sing, etc.)
// A person can play different instruments in different bands he or she is in

5. BandMembersRoles { id, memberId, instrumentId, ... }

Now, if I want to get all members from a specific band, I would write a query like this:

```
SELECT
    p.id AS personId,
    p.name,
    bm.isGuest,
    bm.id AS bandMemberId

FROM people AS p
JOIN BandMembers AS bm
    ON p.id = bm.Id
WHERE bm.bandId = 1
```

And in Sequelize the same result would be achieved by this:

```
// In models config:

db.People.belongsToMany(db.Bands, {
    through: 'BandMembers',
    foreignKey: "personId"
})

db.Bands.belongsToMany(db.People, {
    through: 'BandMembers',
    as: 'members',
    foreignKey: "bandId"
})

. . .


// In models config:

exports.findByBand = (req, res) => {
    Person.findAll({
    // This is a way to get band members only by specific band, please let me know if there is more elegant way for this:
        include: [{
            model: Band,
            attributes: [],
            where: { id: req.params.id }
        }],
        attributes: [
            ['id', 'personId'],
            [db.Sequelize.col('bands.BandMembers.id'), 'bandMemberId'],
            ['name'],
            [db.Sequelize.col('bands.BandMembers.isGuest'), 'isGuest']
        ]
    })
    .then(data => {
        // ...
    })
}
```

Now, if wanted each band member's role in the specific band, in PHP I would create a code like this:

```
// First, store the MySQL Query above in $personQuery

$memStmt = $conn->prepare($personQuery);
$memStmt->bindParam(':bandId', $bandId);
$memStmt->execute();

$memArr = array();

while ($mem = $memStmt->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC)) {
    extract($mem);

    // *** Get Roles
    $roleArr = array();

    $roleQuery = "SELECT
            r.id AS id,
            r.name
        FROM roles AS r
            JOIN BandMembersRoles AS bmr
                ON bm.id = r.memberId
            WHERE bm.id = :bandMemberId;

    $roleStmt = $conn->prepare($roleQuery);
    $roleStmt->bindParam(':m2b_id', $m2b_id);
    $roleStmt->execute();

    while ($role = $roleStmt->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC)) {
        extract($role);

        $roleItem  = array(
            'id' => (int)$id,
            'name' => $name
        );

        array_push($roleArr, $roleItem);
    }
    // *** End of Get Roles

// and the add it to member object...
```

. . .

So, my question is: is it possible in Sequelize to include the instruments of a band member via some include code or by any other way?

Thank you!

Comment: you can do this by relations and foreign_key like `db.People.hasMany(db.Instruments, {
    foreignKey: "personId"
})` and you have to include the model in your query

Comment: There's no direct relation between people and instruments. They are related in the context of the band they are in. Each person can be in several bands and their roles in different band can be different. So actually the scheme is like this: there are People, and there are Bands, there's a linking table which connects between the people and the bands (many-to-many relationship), and this linking table has its id, let's call it p2b_id (to be continued...)

Comment: [...continued] And then there's an Instruments table which contains a list of all available instruments and another linking table which connects between the instruments and the people-in-bands not people per se. I.e. the foreign key inside this intrument-to-person-in-a-band person is NOT the id of the person in the People table, but their id in the first linking table (person-to-band), the one we called p2b_id.